# return value assignment issue(for primitive datatype)

Tags: java

Why do i need to define result variable in below code when primitive have default value.

```
public class DevideByZero {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(devidebyzero());
    }


    public static double devidebyzero() {
        double result;//why do i need to define result when primitive have default value
        try{
            System.out.println("inside try block");
            return (double) (1/0);
        }finally{
            System.out.println("inside final");
            return result;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: A primitive variable inside a method, isn't initialized with a default value.

Comment: @Arnaud - why though?

Comment: `result` is a **local** variable (not a **class** variable).

Comment: "Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable", see Default Values here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Well the "why" for that difference is related to how data (classes and their fields) and methods (code) are handled in hardware. To put objects into memory you'll need to know their size and any primitive  and reference will take up some portion of the memory required for that object. This memory _will_ have a value in any case so a default one will be provided to make it predictive. Methods and code are handled differently and using different hardware (e.g. cpu registers).

Answer (score 5):

Here is an extract from [JLS 4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) :

> Each *class* variable, *instance* variable, or array component is
>   initialized with a default value when it is created

But in your case it is a *local* variable, then :

> A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be **explicitly** given a value
>   before it is used